# Add mailing list subscription form to Blogger

Tags: forms, blogger, mailing-list, google-groups

Our mountain bike club has a blogger site. We send out lots of emails about group rides, trail work, etc. I would like to be able to keep our mailing list up to date. I was thinking about adding a form for people to subscribe to the email list, and a link in the emails to unsubscribe.

Everything I have found about mailing list subscription is to send an email each time there is a post to the blog, but I want to just add it to a group that we could use to send emails. Maybe add the emails to a text file or google group and when you click on the email link it opens a new email to that group. What is the best way to make that happen?

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for what I was trying to do. I created a Google Group and sent everyone invitations to join the group. So far it seems to work fine.